# Agregar componente dinámico Angular 8 por cada click en elemento <li>

Tags: angular, angular8

La situación es la siguiente.Estoy haciendo un chat tipo facebook.Tengo mi listado de usuarios en el componente principal(app-component) y lo que quiero lograr es que al darle click a cada usuario se muestre una ventana de chat con los mensajes que ha enviado ese usuario al que le di click,si le doy click a dos usuarios deberia mostrar las cajas de mensajes de cada uno una al lado de la otra,idéntico al funcionamiento del chat de facebook.La caja donde mostraré los mensajes están en otro componente llamado conversacion.Soy nuevo en angular disculpen si es algo muy básico pero agradecería la ayuda.Mi código es el siguiente:

```
app.component.html
<div class="sidenav">
  <ul *ngFor="let persona of personas">
    <li><a id="{{persona.id}}">{{persona.nombre}}</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

conversacion.component.html

```
    <div class="screen"style="position: fixed;bottom: 10vh;right: 200px">
        <div style="height: 20px;background-color: red">
            Chat
        </div>
        <div class="conversation"#scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight" *ngIf="messages.length > 0">

            <div class="messages" [ngClass]="{'messages--sent': message.userId == user , 'messages--received': message.userId != user }" *ngFor="let message of messages">
                <div class="message">
                    <div class="user">{{ message.userId.username }}<span class="range admin">Dev</span></div>
                    <p> {{ message.message }} </p>
                    <time>{{ message.time }}</time>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
        <div class="text-bar">
            <div class="text-bar__field" id="form-message">
            <textarea type="text" #msgInput (keydown)="autoResize($event)" (keydown.enter)="sendMessage(msgInput.value);false;msgInput.value='';" placeholder="Say something">
            </textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ChatService} from "./services/chat.service";
import {Mensaje} from "./models/mensaje";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers:[ChatService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'chat';
  public id_usuario_destino:number;
  public personas:Array<any>;
  public id_persona:number;
  constructor(private  _chatService:ChatService){
    this.personas=[
        {id:"2",
         nombre:"sergio"
        },
        {id:"3",
            nombre:"jhoyner"
        },
        {id:"4",
            nombre:"gerardo"
        },
        {id:"5",
            nombre:"fabrizio"
        }
    ]
  }

    enviaid(id){
        this.id_usuario_destino=id.id;
      this.id_persona=this.id_usuario_destino;
        this._chatService.getMessages(1,this.id_usuario_destino).subscribe(
            response=>{
                console.log(response)

            },
            error=>{
                console.log(error);
            }
        );

    }
}
```

Me gustaría lograr esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola!, la pregunta concreta sería como pasar la informacion correspondiente para hacer corresponder el listado de usuarios con los mensajes?

Comment: Si,inicialmente solo tengo el listado de usuarios,necesito que al darle click a uno salga la ventana con los mensajes que el ha enviado y los del usuario que entro al sistema,si le di click a 2 usuarios saldrian 2 ventanas cada uno con sus mensajes y asi sucesivamente...

Comment: Necesito pasar la informacion pero que tben por cada informacion que se muestre una caja html con dicha información,algo como la imagen que mostré...soy nuevo en angular y no tengo idea de como lograr ese comportamiento,basicamente es lograr el mismo comportamiento del chat de facebook,sacar las cajas con los mensajes y poder cerrarlas,si pudiera ayudarme con eso se lo agradecería

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo haría en tú caso sería crear array de conversaciones. Luego en el componente que quieres que se vean las conversaciones haces un `*ngFor`. En el caso de que sea en el `app.component.html` simplemente realiza lo siguiente:

```
<div *ngFor="let conversacion of conversaciones">
   <app-conversacion></app-conversacion>
</div>
```

Si tienes todo el CSS preparado para que se vea bien, cada vez que hagas click en un usuario simplemente añádelo al array y Angular automáticamente lo mostrará con el `*ngFor`.